# Equivalent of Apache OpenWhisk Action Sequences in OpenFaas

Tags: serverless, function-composition, openwhisk, openfaas

Apache OpenWhisk has the concept of Action Sequence. Where if we write, for example, functions `f1` and `f2` we can write a command which shall compose the functions in such a way that the output of `f1` shall be piped to `f2`.

For example, we have the first action as`function1` :

```js
function main(params) {

    return {
        string: params.text
    };

}
```

And take the second action, `function2` as follows:

```js
function main(params){
    
    return{
        string: "Hello,"+params.string   
    };
}
```

Then we compose a new action as :

```
$ wsk action create fun2_o_fun1 --sequence function1,function2
```

And we invoke the new action as usual:

```
$ wsk action invoke fun2_o_fun1 -b -r -p text "Abhishek"
```

And we get the output as follows:

```
{ string: 'Hello,Abhishek' }
```

We note that [here](https://ericstoekl.github.io/faas/developer/chaining_functions/) in the case of OpenFaaS the output of one function is automatically fed to the next function in the sequence when we create a new action with the `--sequence` directive.

But here, in the case of OpenFaaS, we use a naive Linux-based utility to pipe the outputs of one function to the input of another. (This is done on the client side). But we try to create a wrapper that achieves the same for the server side.

Is this the only equivalent?